# How to produce horizontal and vertical lines with a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, horizontal-line, vertical-partitioning

So this is my class. I'm trying to get the print() method to print out a horizontal line above my array and another line below my array. I also want to have vertical lines between each number in my array. Okay, I fixed my horizontal lines. Now I'm just lost on how to put vertical lines at the beginning and the end of my arrays.

```
public class Array{

private int[] array;

public Array(int numElements)
{
    array = new int[numElements];
}

public void fill()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int) (10*Math.random());
    } 
}

public void print()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 2*array.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        if(i == array.length - 1)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("|");
        }
    }

    for(int n = 0; n < 2*array.length; n++)
    {
        System.out.print("-");

    }
    System.out.println();
}

public void sort()
{
    int n = array.length;
    boolean swapped;

    do
    {
        swapped = false;

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(array[i-1] > array[i])
            {
                int tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i-1];
                array[i-1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);
}

public void printFrequency()
{
    int[] countArray = new int[10];
    for(int x : array)
    {
        countArray[x]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("There are " + countArray[i] + ", " + i + "'s ");
    }
}
}
```

This is my output:

```
Original:
-----------
1|5|9|3|3
-----------
Sorted:
-----------
1|3|3|5|9
-----------
Frequencies:
There are 0, 0's 
There are 1, 1's 
There are 0, 2's 
There are 2, 3's 
There are 0, 4's 
There are 1, 5's 
There are 0, 6's 
There are 0, 7's 
There are 0, 8's 
There are 1, 9's 

Original:
---------------------
7|0|5|2|0|1|8|0|7|7
---------------------
Sorted:
---------------------
0|0|0|1|2|5|7|7|7|8
---------------------
Frequencies:
There are 3, 0's 
There are 1, 1's 
There are 1, 2's 
There are 0, 3's 
There are 0, 4's 
There are 1, 5's 
There are 0, 6's 
There are 3, 7's 
There are 1, 8's 
There are 0, 9's
```

My output should look like this:

```
Original:
-----------
|1|5|9|3|3|
-----------
Sorted:
-----------
|1|3|3|5|9|
-----------
Frequencies:
There are 0, 0's
There are 1, 1's
There are 0, 2's
There are 2, 3's
There are 0, 4's
There are 1, 5's
There are 0, 6's
There are 0, 7's
There are 0, 8's
There are 1, 9's

Original:
---------------------
|7|0|5|2|0|1|8|0|7|7|
---------------------
Sorted:
---------------------
|0|0|0|1|2|5|7|7|7|8|
---------------------
Frequencies:
There are 3, 0's
There are 1, 1's
There are 1, 2's
There are 0, 3's
There are 0, 4's
There are 1, 5's
There are 0, 6's
There are 3, 7's
There are 1, 8's
There are 0, 9's
```

Comment: The first for loop in your print function does the trick.

Comment: Okay, what about adding a vertical line at the beginning and end of my arrays? What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the line `System.out.println();` outside of your for loop if you don't want to create a new line after each dash character.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It wasn't appearing below working before, but now it is. I still don't understand how to make the line as long as my array though. Nevermind, I figured that part out. I'm just stuck on the vertical lines now.

Answer (score 0):

take the `println()` out of this loop :

```
for(int n = 0; n < array.length; n++)
{
    System.out.print("-");
    System.out.println();
}
```